# What is the difference between a vector and its transpose?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have seen a definition of orthogonality between two vectors something like this:

$$<\vec{u}, \vec{v}> = u^T \cdot v = 0$$

I am wondering what is the purpose of using a transpose of a vector (in this case and in general). I have also seen this in the formula to find the projection of a vector over another, but I have used just the normal vector instead of its transpose and everything seems to work.

Comment: From a technical point of view, it anly comes from the identigfication of a vector with a column-matrix, and the way product of matrices is defined.

Comment: It actually depends on what exactly you take that $\cdot$ symbol to mean: if it's the dot product, then it should be $u \cdot v$, since the dot product operates on two vectors. If it's the matrix product, (considering $u$ and $v$ as matrices, then you get $u^T \cdot v$ or just $u^Tv$, just as we would write $A \cdot B$ or $AB$.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, the difference is one of dual spaces. Low-level explanation: a vector is acted on by matrices by
$$ v \mapsto Av. $$
The transpose of a vector (also called a covector) is acted on by
$$ a \to aA, $$
i.e. we multiply on the *left* for vectors and the *right* for covectors. The product of a covector $u^T$ and a vector $v$, in that order, is a number, which is the same as $\langle u, v \rangle$.

Mid-level, linear algebra explanation: Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $k$. The transpose takes the vectors $v \in V$ to linear maps in the *dual space*, normally called $V^* $. This is originally thought of as the set of *linear maps* on $V$: that is, $\alpha \in V^*$ is a function $V \to k$ such that
$$ \alpha(\lambda u+\mu v) = \lambda \alpha(u) + \mu \alpha(v) $$
for all $u,v \in V$, $\lambda,\mu \in k$.

Now, if $V$ is also equipped with an inner product $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle : V \times V \to k$, and satisfies some other conditions (finite-dimensional's good enough for now) one can show that every element of $V^*$ can be written in the form
$$ \alpha(\cdot) = \langle u , \cdot \rangle, $$
for some $u \in V$. This is basically what $u^{T}$ is. To see how matrices act on these things, consider the member of $k$ given by $u^T A v$, where $A$ is a linear map $V \to V$ (or matrix, if you choose a basis). This can either be written as
$$ u^T (Av) = \langle u, Av \rangle, $$
or, using $u^T A = (A^T u)^T$, as
$$ (u^T A) v = (A^T u)^T v = \langle A^T u, v \rangle. $$
(This is normally actually the definition of the adjoint/transpose of $A$, but I'm trying to explain from a basic point-of-view.) You can go on to talk about bases, how to change them, and so on. Wikipedia no doubt has some good articles on this, since its general linear algebra coverage is excellent.

(There's a stupidly high-powered category-theoretic answer too, but I'll spare all of us the details: basically the transpose is a contravariant functor that takes the category of vector spaces over a field to its opposite category, and so on...)

Answer (score 4):

So in general the transpose of a vector is a linear mapping of vectors to scalars.

There are many reasons to consider them distinctly. One of them is that it makes it really simple to distinguish these two expressions:$$\mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}^T ~~\text{vs.}~~ \mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{b}$$In another notation borrowed from quantum mechanics you can see the difference even more directly:$$| a \rangle\langle b | ~~\text{vs.}~~ \langle a | b \rangle$$one is an inner product (a scalar); the other is an outer product (a matrix). If we just wrote $\mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}$ we would lack this distinction. In fact in yet another notation, called abstract-index notation, we can write things like $a^i b_j c_k$, which is a "product" of three vectors which maps an ordinary vector to a matrix. So being able to simply make these distinctions is helpful. It's great to be able to say things like $\det A = 0 ~\text{iff}~ A = \mathbf u \mathbf u^T$.

That notational convenience gives us a trebuchet to launch our understanding into new mathematics: suppose that instead of identifying the components $v_i = v^i$ as being absolutely identical, we allow an invertible matrix to sit between them: $v_m = \sum_n g_{mn} ~ v^n$. Then we find that actually, the norm of a vector in such a space is $\sum_m v_m ~ v^m = \sum_{mn} g_{mn} ~ v^m ~v^n$ which might not be $\sum_n v^n ~ v^n$. You can now begin to talk about the curvature of the space in terms of details of $g_{mn}$ and how it interacts with derivative operators $\partial_k$ -- in other words you can start to think about manifolds. Or you can do some useful physics -- in particular, this lets us model things like special relativity, where everyone who has some individual idea $(ct, x, y, z)$ of where and when an event happens will all (due to the way the laws work) agree on the number $(ct)^2 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2$. If you insert those negatives for the transposes (duals) of your vectors consistently you'll get a very simple, easy-to-follow mathematics. If you try to work with the vectors $(ct, ix, iy, iz)$ you will have more trouble. One example is that the electromagnetic field tensor is $\partial_i A_j - \partial_j A_i$, it is completely obvious why you want the dual vector to $A^i$ here and not the vector itself (because it'd be a type error to do $\partial_i A^j - \partial_j A^i$ and therefore wouldn't map to any real quantity!).

Even if you're not doing relativity or differential geometry, you might prefer a different basis for your dual vectors. For example, in order to get the simple expression$$\vec a \cdot \vec b = a_x ~ b_x + a_y ~ b_y + a_z ~ b_z $$there is actually a pretty huge step taken, if you think about the more general expression$$\vec a \cdot \vec b = \sum_{mn} a_m ~ b_n ~ \hat e_m \cdot \hat e_n$$The huge step is to say that $$\hat e_m \cdot \hat e_n = \delta_{mn} = 1 ~\text{if}~ m = n ~\text{else}~ 0.$$But what if you're dealing with a crystal where it has really simple crystal properties only in a handful of directions which are **not** mutually orthogonal? There are lots of lattices that are not rectangular! Then you're in a skewed coordinate system and you'll want your basis vectors to be *non-orthogonal*. A good dual space in this circumstance rescues you from madness. You start with your skewed basis vectors $\hat e_m$ and invent their "transposes" or duals $\hat e^m$ such that $\hat e^m \cdot \hat e_n = \delta^m_n = 1 ~\text{if}~ m = n ~\text{else}~ 0.$In other words, we choose (in 3D) for $\hat e^1$ the vector which is perpendicular with $\hat e_2$ and $\hat e_3$ and has dot product $1$ when dotted into $\hat e_1$. Then the coordinates of your new "dual vectors" (expressed in terms of those coordinates) live in a "dual space" to your normal vector space, but you can now restore the simple-ish law $\vec a \cdot \vec b = a_x ~ b^x + a_y ~ b^y + a_z ~ b^z$.

In general the answer is, "because you can do a lot more stuff if you can keep things which are similar-but-not-quite-the-same mentally distinct: lots of things become less confusing."

Answer (score 1):

**Redefinition of the dot product**

This notation is actually a redefinition of the dot product using matrix multiplication. Let $\small \vec u, \vec v \in \mathbb{R}^n$:

- Matrix $\small u^T$ is the [row vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_vectors) of $\small \vec u$, a $\small 1 \times n$ matrix.
- Matrix $\small v$ the column vector of $\small \vec v$, a $\small n \times 1$ matrix.

When such matrices are multiplied, the result is the dot product of the corresponding vectors (well that's not strictly exact, see last section):

$$
u^T \; v
=
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \: 2 \: 3\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ 5 \\ 6\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ 5 \\ 6\end{bmatrix}
=
\vec u \cdot \vec v
$$

Matrices have sizes $\small 1 \times n$ and $\small n \times 1$. This operation is defined on matrices.

If you don't take the transpose of $\small \vec u$ when converting to matrices, then you have a multiplication of matrices which are column vectors:

$$
u \; v
=
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ 5 \\ 6\end{bmatrix}
$$

The multiplication of a matrix $\small n \times 1$ by a matrix $\small n \times 1$ is not defined.

Note there is a mistake on your equation, the dot product operator symbol is used instead of nothing (for the matrix multiplication).

**Vector vs. matrix transpose**

> What is the difference between a vector and its transpose?

Transposition is defined for a matrix. The transpose operation means converting row to columns and vice-versa.

A vector has no row or column representation, it's only a list of values. However a vector is easily mapped to a matrix, with either one row or one column.

The "transpose of a vector" is actually the transpose of the row vector matrix built from the vector. The result is a column vector matrix.

**Confusing notation**

It's sometimes difficult to understand whether some representation is a row/column matrix or a vector, as visible on the examples above. When this happens it's possible to sort out the confusion by looking at the operators, some are specific to matrices, some are specific to vectors.

Similarly, the matrix multiplication shown above  actually results in a $\small 1 \times 1$ matrix, which single element is a scalar, the dot product of corresponding vectors.

So it's not exact to state $\small u^T \, v = \vec u \cdot \vec v$, but this is the way it is [usually taught](https://mathinsight.org/dot_product_matrix_notation).