# Understanding the relation between multiplication order of covectors and interpretation as linear functionals

Tags: linear-algebra

I have read over similar discussions in other questions, e.g. here: [What is the difference between a vector and its transpose?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1245622/what-is-the-difference-between-a-vector-and-its-transpose)

But I'm still confused about covectors and their relation to matrix multiplication. Wikipedia says the *definition* of a covector is an element of the dual. But vectors and covectors are also just ordered sets of $n$ elements from the underlying field. In this way, they are interchangeable. We also multiply vectors on the right (of a matrix) and covectors on the left. Can this fact be deduced from the definition of a covector? Is it in some way natural, or is there a design choice here in the way we write them as rows/columns? Is the transpose of a vector *defined* as the covector with the same field elements in the same order?

What I'd like to get is one simple definition for a vector and one simple definition for a covector from which the multiplication order and the fact that they're transposes of each other follow naturally.

I'm sorry if there are a lot of questions all in one here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "But vectors and covectors are also just ordered sets of n elements from the underlying field."

No. that's not at all what they are. If you fix a vector space $V$ over a field $F$, then by convention, we call elements of $V$ vectors and elements of $V^*=\text{Hom}(V,F)$ covectors. $V$ could be any abstract vector space, so a-priori, there is no meaning at all in thinking of elements of $V$ as ordered tuples of numbers. Also $V$ and $V^*$ are completely different spaces and in general you should never conflate the two.

Even if you're considering the special case where $V=F^n$ for some positive integer $n$, $(F^n)^*$ and $F^n$ are still completely different spaces, so they're not equal. Furthermore, there is no natural isomorphism between these spaces, so there's no reason at all to think they're the same thing. It is only AFTER you choose a basis $\beta$ for a (finite-dimensional) vector space that you can construct an isomorphism $\Phi_{\beta}:V\to V^*$.

So, in this sense, your entire conception of vectors and covectors seems to be misguided by your thinking in terms of row/column vectors.

---

So, what is the relationship between vectors (i.e elements of $V$) covectors (elements of $V$) and vertical ordered lists of numbers (column vectors) and horizontal lists of numbers (row vectors)? Well, it all stems from choosing a basis for $V$.

If you have a basis $\beta=\{v_1,\dots, v_n\}$ for $V$, then given any $v\in V$, there exist unique $a_1,\dots, a_n\in F$ such that $v=\sum_{i=1}^na_iv_i$. In this case, we can write
\begin{align}
[v]_{\beta}&=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1\\\vdots \\a_n
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
We call $[v]_{\beta}$ **the coordinate representation of $v\in V$ relative to the basis $\beta$.**

Next thing we shall discuss is matrix representations of linear transformations. So let $V,W$ be vector spaces over $F$, let $\beta=\{v_1,\dots, v_n\}$ be a basis for $V$, let $\gamma=\{w_1,\dots, w_m\}$ be a basis for $W$, and let $T:V\to W$ be a given linear transformation. In this case, we can associate with $T$, a certain rectangular array of numbers $[T]_{\beta}^{\gamma}$ called **the matrix representation of $T$ relative to the ordered basis $\beta$ and $\gamma$**. This will be a certain $m\times n$ matrix with entries coming from the field $F$. How is this matrix obtained? Well, for each $v_j\in \beta$, we can consider $T(v_j)\in W$. Since $\gamma=\{w_1,\dots, w_m\}$ is a basis, there exist unique scalars $a_{1j},\dots, a_{mj}\in F$ such that
\begin{align}
T(v_j)= \sum_{i=1}^ma_{ij}w_i
\end{align}
So, we take this whole massive collection of numbers $a_{11},\dots, a_{m1}, a_{12}\dots, a_{m2},\dots, a_{1n},\dots a_{mn}$ and stick it into a rectangular array (a matrix):
\begin{align}
[T]_{\beta}^{\gamma}&:=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & \dots &a_{1n}\\
\vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\
a_{m1}&\dots & a_{mn}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

I hope you appreciate the difference: $T$ is an element of $\text{Hom}(V,W)$ and it is the thing we are really interested about, while $[T]_{\beta}^{\gamma}\in M_{m\times n}(F)$ is just a rectangular array of numbers, and until you appreciate the significance of the basis-free development of linear algebra, you should not assign any extra significance to this array of numbers other than that it is a convenient short-hand way of keeping track of some information.

Now, what you can prove is that for any $v\in V$, we have
\begin{align}
[T(v)]_{\gamma}&=[T]_{\beta}^{\gamma}\cdot[v]_{\beta}
\end{align}
What is this saying? Well, if you start with a vector $v\in V$ and a linear map $T:V\to W$, then $T(v)\in W$. So, the equation above is telling you that the coordinate representation of $T(v)$ is obtained by multiplying the matrix representation of $T$, with the coordinate representation of $v$.

---

Now, consider what a covector is: it is an element of $V^*$, i.e it is a linear map $\lambda:V\to F$, so said once again, in the discussion above, we're considering the special case of $W=F$. Again, we are fixing a basis $\beta=\{v_1,\dots, v_n\}$ for $V$. What is a basis for $F$? Well, the most obvious one is $\gamma=\{1\}$ ;i.e it is a basis consisting of only one element, namely the element $1\in F$. So, by the conventioned described above, we can consider the matrix representation of the linear transformation $\lambda$, which gives us a $ (\dim F)\times (\dim V)=1\times n$ matrix $[\lambda]_{\beta}^{\gamma}=[\lambda]_{\beta}^{\{1\}}$.

At this stage a very tempting thing to do is the following: start with a $\lambda\in V^*$, then write out its $1\times n$ matrix representation, say
\begin{align}
[\lambda]_{\beta}^{\{1\}}&= 
\begin{pmatrix}
c_1 & \dots &c_n
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Now, you can look at the vector $v=\sum_{i=1}^nc_iv_i$. This has the coordinate representation
\begin{align}
[v]_{\beta}&=
\begin{pmatrix}
c_1\\\vdots\\c_n
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

So, now if you just look at the numbers alone, and completely forget everything I've told you about the importance of the distinction between vectors and covectors, you'll (rightfully) say that the only difference between these things is that one list of numbers is given horizontally while the other is given vertically.

What I have just described is a way of associating to each element of $V^*$ a certain element of $V$. You can infact reverse this procedure. What this means is I've described for you an isomorphism $V^*\to V$ which assigns to each $\lambda \in V^*$ an element $v\in V$ according to the procedure described above. But of course, you should keep in mind that $\lambda \neq v$ (of course, how can they be equal if they live in different spaces). The correct relationship is that $[\lambda]_{\beta}^{\{1\}}=([v]_{\beta})^t$.

---

One final thing I should mention is that transpose of a matrix comes in the following manner: suppose I have a linear transformation $T:V\to W$. Then, this "induces" a very natural linear map $T^*:W^*\to V^*$ defined by $T^*(\phi):= \phi\circ T$. This is called the pull-back/transpose map of $T$. The reason for this terminology is that if you take a basis $\beta$ of $V$, $\gamma$ of $W$, and you consider their dual bases $\beta^*$ of $V^*$ and $\gamma^*$ of $W^*$, then
\begin{align}
[T^*]_{\gamma^*}^{\beta^*}&= \left([T]_{\beta}^{\gamma}\right)^t
\end{align}
The fact that $T:V\to W$ while $T^*:W^*\to V^*$ seems to go in the "opposite direction" is exactly why if you unwind all the definitions carefully, you'll see that the matrix representation of $T^*$ is the transpose of the matrix representation of $T$ (the fact that the linear map "goes the other way" is reflected in the fact that the matrix representation is somehow "flipped", i.e transposed).